# Async/await logic in protractor tests doesn't detect a page element

Tags: angular, selenium, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I am new to writing e2e tests in protractor. 
I started using async await in protractor tests and added browser wait as well. Below is my code.
The problem the menuBtn is never found by protractor and it timesout. I tried using ExpectedCOnditions of visilityOf and presenceOf. but they all hang there and never get resolved.
I thought that I am giving a wrong locator. However when use $x('xPath on line 3') it detects it on the web page.
Could anyone please help on this.

```
async menuNav(title, pageElement) {
    browser.sleep(3000);
    // browser.waitForAngular();
    const menuBtn = element(by.xpath('.//mat-icon[@id="' + pageElement + '"]'));

    console.log('menu btn: ', menuBtn.locator());
    await browser.wait(() => {
        return browser.isElementPresent(menuBtn);
    }, 3000);

    await menuBtn[0].click();
    const  menuTitle = element(by.xpath('.//*[contains(text(),\''  + title + '\')]'));
    browser.sleep(3000);
    menuTitle.isPresent().then(result => {
        expect(result).toBe(true);
        console.log('inside is present');
        console.log(title);
    });

}
```

This is how the HTML looks like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items"
    class="item"
    placement="right"
    container="body"
    containerClass="sidebar-tooltip">

    <mat-icon class="icon" [id]="item.id" [svgIcon]="item.icon"></mat-icon>
  </div>
```

Based on comments from @Gunderson and @SimonN I added await before the element locators. But I thought that they are just definitions since I am not using protractor locators like findByElement. However I changed the code and it still blocks at menuBtn.click and this my code now:

```
async menuNav(title, pageElement) {
    browser.sleep(3000)
    const menuBtn = await element(by.xpath('.//mat-icon[@id="' + pageElement + '"]'));

    browser.wait(() => {
        return browser.isElementPresent(menuBtn);
    }, 3000);

    return menuBtn.isPresent().then(elementAvailable =>  {
        browser.wait(this.EC.elementToBeClickable(menuBtn), 3000).then(async () => {
            await menuBtn.click();
            const menuTitle = await element(by.xpath('.//*[contains(text(),\''  + title + '")]'));
            return browser.wait(this.EC.presenceOf(menuTitle), 3000).then(() => {
                return true;
            });
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error: ', error);
    });

}
```

Comment: would need to see the html of the page to help. Using protractor means you probably shouldn't have to do any waiting as it takes care of all that for you. I presume your locator for the element is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you @Simon . This there is an array of divs with mat-icons nested inside them.  and i am trying to get that mat-icon with the id of which is [id]="item.id"

Comment: For a start you are finding one element (menuBtn) and then trying to click menuBtn[0]. You haven't got an array of elements. If you want all elements you need elements.all. I will add code I think should work as an answer

Comment: An array came out in the browser console so I added it that way. But later I replaced the xpath with simple id which is                                                       
         const menuBtn = element(by.id(pageElement));      and I still get same problem.

Comment: You need to add `await` ahead of each protractor API. You missed `await` at  two `browser.sleep(3000);` and at `menuTitle.isPresent()`.  Additionally, you need to set `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` in protractor conf.  Get more info from http://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await

Comment: added await before browser.sleep() Still it gets stuck at await menuBtn.click(). I am sure it's a locator issue now. But I don't understand what is wrong with my locator. I use element(by.id(pageElement)). this when added on the browser console, hightlights the element in the actual application but protractor hangs there trying to find it.

Comment: Dont you need to `await` on your locators as well?  `await element(by.xpath('.//mat-icon[@id="' + pageElement + '"]'));`

Comment: good point @Gunderson . I didnt see that. I think that should fix it

Answer (score 2):

@yong is right in his comments, you are missing `await` in various places.  It needs to be in front of all Protractor functions, including locators. You shouldn't need any sleeps either, but I'll leave them there for now:

```
async menuNav(title, pageElement) {
    await browser.sleep(3000);  <-- missed await here
    const menuBtn = await element(by.xpath('.//mat-icon[@id="' + pageElement + '"]')); <-- missed await here

    await menuBtn[0].click(); <-- this isn't an ElementArray, so not sure why [0] is there
    const  menuTitle = await element(by.xpath('.//*[contains(text(),\''  + title + '\')]')); <-- missed await here
    await browser.sleep(3000); <-- missed await here
    // no need to use .then() here either
    expect(await menuTitle.isPresent()).toBe(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using async/await and promise chains don't really work too well together so that might cause you a few issues (although not the exact issue you're facing. Here's what I would try to resolve your problem. Try this:

```
    async menuNav(title, pageElement) {
const menuBtn = element(by.xpath('.//mat-icon[@id="' + pageElement + '"]'));
console.log('menu btn: ', menuBtn.locator());

await menuBtn.click();
const  menuTitle = element(by.xpath('.//*[contains(text(),\''  + title + '\')]'));
browser.sleep(3000);
menuTitle.isPresent().then(result => {
    expect(result).toBe(true);
    console.log('inside is present');
    console.log(title);
});
```

}

If there are multiple elements with id of item.id I would do this:

```
    async menuNav(title, pageElement) {
const menuBtn = element.all(by.xpath('.//mat-icon[@id="' + pageElement + '"]'));
console.log('menu btn: ', menuBtn.locator());

await menuBtn[0].click();
const  menuTitle = element(by.xpath('.//*[contains(text(),\''  + title + '\')]'));
browser.sleep(3000);
menuTitle.isPresent().then(result => {
    expect(result).toBe(true);
    console.log('inside is present');
    console.log(title);
});
```

Comment: I tried this one and it gets stuck at await menuBtn.click() and timesout after that. It gives me `Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 20 seconds`. Increasing the scriptTimeout in config also doesnot resolve this

Comment: seen as you're using async/await, have you disabled control flow? i.e. SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false

Comment: Yes... Did that.. not sure if I need to add any other configuration.

Comment: can you also do this instead: const menuBtn = element(by.id(pageElement));

Comment: Tried that too... tried multiple ways they all work on the browser console but protractor fails to locate them somehow.

Comment: there are no iframes on your page? I doubt it but just checking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186509/discussion-between-divya-and-simon-n).

Comment: There are no iframes but multiple nested components are there. My assumption is that once the page is loaded it should not matter. Or do I need to provide a relative path to find the element?